# SwiftUI - Trigger a Menu without tap (custom accessibility action)

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility

I have a list view of 'groceries'
Each cell contains a label, and an 'add' button
If you tap 'add' button, a `Menu` with has a list of shopping lists you can add to.

This is fine, however, for voice-over, I wanted to add an accessibility action so a user doesn't have to tap the button. I want that element to be hidden by accessibility, and an action instead.

Is it possible to somehow trigger a menu into showing without tapping?

**Example:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Vertical list of shopping items
        VStack { 
            // Shopping Item Cell
            HStack { 
                Text("Apple")

                Spacer()

                // Non-accessible button (voice over users use actions)
                Menu("Shopping Lists") {
                    Button("List 01", action: {})
                    Button("List 02", action: {})
                    Button("List 03", action: {})
                }
                label: { 
                    Image(systemName: "add")
                }
                .accessibilityElement(hidden: true)
            }
            
            .accessibilityAction { 
                // somehow open the menu
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey @Rye did you manage to do that?

Comment: Hey @TiagoMendes, I wasn't able to figure it out with `Menu` sadly and gave up. In hindsight, you could probably add a custom modal popup with the options and invoke that by a custom action, but not an ideal solution. I raised a feedback ticket FB9548264 for this though. Will update if I hear back.